# How to use native OpenGL with Qt 5.4?

Tags: qt, opengl

I want to use Qt 5.4 to create a window and render with normal OpenGL functions some stuff in that window. In the last few days, I read a lot about the Qt classes and how to initialize OpenGL and so on. I think, the main classes I have to deal with are QOpenGLWindow or QOpenGLWidget, but there are the QSurface and some other classes too. Now I am very unsure about what doing next and which class I should use to use the plain OpenGL functions, later. Can someone explain more clearly to me what I have to do to set up a Qt GUI in which I can use plain OpenGL?

Some other questions from me are:

- At which point does Qt create a plain OpenGL context? Do I have to use the QOpenGLContext?
- What is exactly the difference between a QSurface and a QOpenGLWindow? In the QOpenGLWindow example both classes are used.
- Is it possible to use glew besides this qt stuff? Here are some question on, which deal with setting up glew with qt, but I think that I did not get the real point of why glew is needed.

Edit: I discussed this question with a colleague and our only conclusion was to use Offscreen-Rendering. Does anyone know another solution?

Comment: Have you looked at the [OpenGL Window Exemple](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html) (although it doesn't use the `QOpenGLWindow` class) ? [`QSurface`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsurface.html) is a pure virtual base class of `QWindow` and so of `QOpenGLWindow` too. Apparently `QOpenGLWindow` works like `QOpenGLWidget` and `QOpenGLWidget` [has more complete documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#details).

Comment: There's also a QOpenGLWindow example shipped with Qt.

Answer (score 2):

> At which point does Qt create a plain OpenGL context? Do I have to use the QOpenGLContext?

Either where it's documented (for instance, creating a `QOpenGLWidget` or a `QOpenGLWindow` will automatically create a context), or you can create a context manually at any time by creating a `QOpenGLContext` object.

> What is exactly the difference between a QSurface and a QOpenGLWindow? In the QOpenGLWindow example both classes are used.

A `QSurface` is a base class representing a "drawable surface" (onscreen or offscreen). `QWindow` is its onscreen implementation (representing a top level window), so it inherits from `QSurface`. You can draw over a `QWindow` by using OpenGL or by using a CPU-based rasterizer.

Finally, `QOpenGLWindow` is a `QWindow` subclass which offers some extra functionality and convenience, by automatically creating and managing an OpenGL context (via `QOpenGLContext`), having an optional partial-update strategy (through the usage of a FBO), etc.

> Is it possible to use glew besides this qt stuff? Here are some question on, which deal with setting up glew with qt, but I think that I did not get the real point of why glew is needed.

**Qt is not in your way**. And it doesn't change your usage of OpenGL in any way. Just use Qt to create a window and a context (in a totally cross platform way), then you're free to use GLEW (to resolve OpenGL function pointers, extensions, etc.) or any 3rd party OpenGL abstraction.

Comment: except that QT IS IN MY WAY because I cannot make my manually created OpenGLContext current on any QWidgets, only QSurfaces, if I want a current OpenGLContext in a QWIdget, I have to resolve to only use the QT managed context that is guaranteed to be current in initializeGL(), paintGL(), and resizeGL()

Comment: A QWidget is not a OpenGL surface, so "making a context current on it" doesn't make sense. You need a real surface to do what you want -- e.g. by using a plain QWindow and wrapping it in a widget via `QWidget::createWindowContainer`. That's not "being in your way", that's playing by the rules of the game (which by the way are dictated by OpenGL, not Qt).

Comment: ok, so I should have mentioned that it is not QWidget, but rather QOpenGlWidget, I can use OpenGL on it, but only if I do it QT's way, that IS "in my way"

Comment: Because QOpenGLWidget is not a window surface. As I said, if you want the "fully native" way, you can: QWindow + QOpenGLContext + QWidget::createWindowSurface. QOpenGLWidget is a different kind of solution, with some pros and cons.

Comment: by the way, QGestures are not supported on QWindows and jamming a QWindow into a QWidget with QWidget::createWindowContainer() has its own set of limitations and known issues

Comment: I'd like to be constructive -- could you please post a question with the problems you're facing with QOpenGLWidget, maybe there's some acceptable solution for you, I'd love to help if possible.

Comment: it's been asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058621/qopenglwidget-with-qapplication